# How do I keep my Qt C++ program from opening a console in Windows?

Tags: c++, windows, qt, console, cmake

I'm making an application in Qt Creator, with cmake and MinGW as compiler. I've seen this question being answered for other people, but they used regular Qt projects with .pro files, while I use a CMakeLists.txt file. So these posts were of no help to me.

The problem is that my application opens a console when booted, and as usual, closing this console will close the application as well. I want to keep the application from opening a console, so that it is more user-friendly for people who don't need any debug information and such.

Comment: Actually, it shouldn't be opening the console by default.

Comment: Not 100% sure, so just a comment, but there should most likely be a `ADD_EXECUTABLE(exename ....)` where of course the dots are other argments. Could you change that to `ADD_EXECUTABLE(exename [WIN32] ...)`?

Comment: Bart, you should make an answer of this, because it is the "CMake recommended" way... The alternative is do to it skyhisi's way with the "-mwindows" link-flag.

Comment: None of the answers seem to solve the issue nowadays (as of 2023).  They are either ineffective or result in a linking error.

Comment: This one solved for me: `if(WIN32) <br>
    set_property(TARGET exename PROPERTY WIN32_EXECUTABLE true) <br>
    target_link_libraries(exename PUBLIC Qt5::WinMain)<br>
endif()` .

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You will most likely have a line such as the following in your CMakeLists.txt:

```
ADD_EXECUTABLE(exename ....)
```

where of course the dots are further arguments. Change this to:

```
ADD_EXECUTABLE(exename [WIN32] ...)
```

to specify that it's a Win32 application and not a console application.

Or, as can be found [on the CMAKE website](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/cmake-2-8-docs.html) "If `WIN32` is given the property `WIN32_EXECUTABLE` will be set on the target created." And when WIN32_EXECUTABLE is set it will "[Build an executable with a WinMain entry point on windows](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/cmake-2-8-docs.html#prop_tgt%3aWIN32_EXECUTABLE)."

Answer (score 16):

By default, and in contrast to qmake,  cmake builds Qt apps with enabled console window under windows (windows binaries can use different entry points - the console window is one of them).

You can disable the console window appearing via setting the [`WIN32_EXECUTABLE`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/WIN32_EXECUTABLE.html#prop_tgt:WIN32_EXECUTABLE) cmake property on the executable.

This can be achieved either via setting an [`add_executable`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_executable.html) option, i.e.

```
add_executable(myexe WIN32 ...)
```

or via setting the property explicitly:

```
set_property(TARGET main PROPERTY WIN32_EXECUTABLE true)
```

Using `set_property()` is helpful when the console window should conditionally be disabled, e.g.:

```
if(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE STREQUAL "Release")
  set_property(TARGET main PROPERTY WIN32_EXECUTABLE true)
endif()
```

The `WIN32_EXECUTABLE` property has no effect when compiling on platforms other than windows (cf. [`CMAKE_WIN32_EXECUTABLE`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_WIN32_EXECUTABLE.html)).

As with the `WIN32` cmake variable, the `WIN32_EXECUTABLE` property also configures the console window when compiling a win64 executable.

Comment: I imagine set_target_properties may also be used.

Comment: @mjwach, yes, `set_target_properties()` arguably is more convenient when you have to set multiple properties on one target, where `set_property(TARGET ...)` arguably yields a more uniform `CMakeLists.txt` - especially when setting properties not only on targets.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, but solved it by adding:

```
#CMakeLists.txt
# ... some text (like finding QT)

LINK_LIBRARIES(${QT_QTMAIN_LIBRARY})

# ... and then

ADD_EXECUTABLE(my_qt_project WIN32 ... )
```

If I don't use `LINK_LIBRARIES(${QT_QTMAIN_LIBRARY})` I get error:

`error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _WinMain@16 referenced in function ___tmainCRTStartup`

Comment: http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/manual/cmake-qt.7.html#qtmain-lib-on-windows

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question, but anyways, there is a better solution than all of the other ones posted here:

```
CMAKE_POLICY(SET CMP0020 NEW)
```

Adding this will automatically handle everything for you. CMake should actually output a warning if you don't set this policy, at least that's how I learned of its existence.

Answer (score 0):

For building with Mingw, add a CMake command:

```
set_target_properties(target_name PROPERTIES LINK_FLAGS "-mwindows")
```

Replace `target_name` with your target's name (first parameter to add_executable)

Comment: I tried this, but it seems to break things for me. If I add this line, then compile, it will say that the compilation has been successful without outputting anything to the .exe file. Even if I put blatant syntax error in my code, it will still tell me that the build was successful.

Comment: @Neko: Try deleting the cmakecache.txt and then build. Sometimes, cmake incorrectly thinks nothing should be rebuilt when you edit you cmakelists.txt