# QMake's CONFIG+=console in CMake

Tags: qt, cmake

In QMake:

```
CONFIG += console
```

How do I get the same effect in CMake?

(specs: Qt 5.0.2, CMake 2.8.10)

Comment: cf. [How do I keep my Qt C++ program from opening a console in Windows?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8249028/how-do-i-keep-my-qt-c-program-from-opening-a-console-in-windows/36527454)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You don't do anything: for CMake, it's the default. If you want a Windows application, you'll need to add the `WIN32` options to the call to [`add_executable`](http://cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.10/cmake.html#command:add_executable):

```
add_executable(<name> [WIN32] [MACOSX_BUNDLE]
               [EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL]
               source1 source2 ... sourceN)
```

This will set the linker to look for `WinMain` instead of `main` as you'd expect for a Windows GUI app, by setting the CMake internal [`WIN32_EXECUTABLE`](http://cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.10/cmake.html#prop_tgt:WIN32_EXECUTABLE).

Comment: This re-enables `qDebug()` output for my project migrated to CMake

Answer (score 0):

To ensure `qDebug()` works correctly, you can add:

```
/* In Header */
#include <QLoggingCategory>

/* After creating QApplication instance */
QLoggingCategory::defaultCategory()->setEnabled(QtDebugMsg, true);
```

Comment: Still not showing up any logs. I can see them if I manually execute binary from terminal, though.