# How to run console application written on Qt creator in terminal?

Tags: terminal, console, qt-creator

I created C++ console application, using cmake. I use the Qt creator v.3.1.2(GCC 4.6.1 64 bit), (Based on Qt 5.3.1). My OS is Ununtu 12.04 (LTS)

1. How can I run my application in terminal (within Qt IDE of
   course)? Now all output typing on "Application Output" window.
2. Does anyone know how to type to "Application Output" window? Because
   when I try to type something to "Application Output" window and
   press "Enter" - nothing happens! Only cursor moving to new line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In project setting there is a check box to run application in terminal window (-I don't remember exact name of check box, but it is easy to find). You will see separate widow when running application.

Problem is debugging. For a longer time there is bug in GDB (used by Qt Creator on all platforms) when debugging console application and waiting for data from console. To overcome this problem prepare file with input data and redirect standard input to this file.

If you run application in normal mode (no debugging) console input works fine.

edit: see [this link](http://qt-project.org/doc/qtcreator-2.6/creator-debugger-operating-modes.html#launching-in-start-internal-mode)

Comment: Yes, this chek box exist in case you are using *.pro file for qmake in your project. Unfortunately, I didn`t find any similar chek boxes in case of _CMake-project_.
Maybe you know any other way to solve this issue. Maybe is reason to type something extra to _Cmakelist.txt_ file (similar way as configuration files, for example like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17331999/qmakes-config-console-in-cmake))

Comment: this is not a setting which is written in *.pro file! It is recorded somewhere in qt creator files for workspace, so same thing applies for any kind of project. I need other machine to prove it.

Comment: did you clicked "Projects" icon on the left? On this page there are build/run settings, where this check box is located.

Comment: Yes it works!!! I clicked _Priject_ then move _Build&Run_ section, then change _Buld_ into _Run_ and see the **Run in terminal** check box. So, after I filled this chekbox my application run on separate terminal window :). Thank you so much!

Comment: @MarekR I know it's been some years but I think the GDB bug is still there as I'm getting "Build ID mismatch between current exec-file and automatically determined exec-file" warning if I run my app in terminal. The link you provided no longer exists and I don't really know what you meant by "redirect standard input to this file". Could you elaborate, if you remember it?